# How do the order of these while statements work?

Tags: python, while-loop

```
def smallestSubWithSum(arr, n, x):
 
    # Initialize current sum and minimum length
    curr_sum = 0
    min_len = n + 1
 
    # Initialize starting and ending indexes
    start = 0
    end = 0
    while (end < n):
 
        # Keep adding array elements while current
        # sum is smaller than or equal to x
        while (curr_sum <= x and end < n):
            curr_sum += arr[end]
            end += 1
 
        # If current sum becomes greater than x.
        while (curr_sum > x and start < n):
 
            # Update minimum length if needed
            if (end - start < min_len):
                min_len = end - start
 
            # remove starting elements
            curr_sum -= arr[start]
            start += 1
 
    return min_len
```

```
def Test(num):
    h = 0
    while h < num:
        while(h%2 == 0):
            print(h)
        while(h%5 == 0):
            print(h)
        h+=1
```

I was taking a look at this code from geeksforgeeks, and I thought that the code would just stay inside the second while statement, and just update end and curr_sum until that condition is broken, and then move onto the third while statement. It doesn't actually work this way though, is it because both these while statements are part of the bigger first while statement? The other way that I thought it might work is that the second while statement iterates once, and then the third while statement iterates once as well, and when all the values are updated the first while statement concludes the code, however I have a feeling this is wrong as well. Can someone tell me how the code actually executes or provide a simpler example I guess?

Edit: I tested what I was talking about, and it does repeatededly print 0, meaning it is stuck in the second while loop. So, for the code in smallestSubWithSum the third while loop should never even execute until the second one is finished and by that point it shouldn't work is what I currently believe, but it's not the case, anyone know the fault in my reasoning?

Comment: iif you cannot figure it by reading the code, add some `print` statements inside the loops and run the code, this will help you understand what is going on. It's the simplest way to understand a code.

Comment: Inner while loops are independent of outer while loops.

Comment: hi rufus, that is the case it works that way in my test I made as well. But for for smallestSubwithsum, it must be the case that the third and second while loop are running together at the same time under the first one, otherwise the code would not work. But again, based on the test that I made that should be impossible

Answer (score 1):

So basically you can add multiple while loops to make to add more specifications to the data, but I would recommend using if and elif loops if there aren't many data specifications.

Here is an example of a number guesser using a while loop

```
import random
counter = 0
rand_num = random.randint(1, 20)
x = input("Number between 1 and 20: ")
print(rand_num)

while x != str(rand_num):
    rand_num = random.randint(1, 20)
    print(rand_num)
    counter += 1

    if x == str(rand_num):
        print("Got It!! It only took " + str(counter) + " tries.")
```